# Windows service - get current directory

Tags: c#, windows-services, working-directory

I have a Windows service that should look for a configuration file in its current directory.

So I use `directory.getcurrentdirectiry()` but instead of the service directory I get back

```
c:\windows\system32
```

Any idea why and how should I get the service directory?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Don't use `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`. I had the same exact problem with *C:\Windows\System32* being returned. Use this instead:

`Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);`

Comment: Apparently you need to add System.Windows.Forms.dll in order for this to work.

Comment: I get "the name application does not exist in the current context"

Answer (score 175):

You can set the current directory to the directory that your service is running from by including this line in your code:

```
System.IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
```

The important part of this is:

```
System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

That returns the path to the directory your service is running from.

Comment: `System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` worked for me, it gives the directory. `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location` returns the directory plus the name of the executable

Comment: This answer works better for different scenarios. I use NCrunch, and the accepted answer wouldn't help there.

Comment: This also works in a broader set of environments (asp.net, winform, and windows services) as compared to other solutions like Assembly.Location and etc.

Comment: System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory worked for me.
Also I made a test using it both as Windows Service and Console Application (inside Linux Container) and works fine in both scenarios! Thanks! :D

Answer (score 33):

Try this:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location
```

Comment: This line give me the directory that the serviec is running BUT also the Assembly itself... sonthig like - c:\serviceDir\app.exe I would like only the directory

Comment: Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)

Answer (score 20):

Getting directory from full path:

```
var location = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;
var directoryPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(location);
```

Quite a silly problem when comparing to writing a Windows service :)

Answer (score 2):

In case you're targeting .NET Core or .NET Standard you could use `AppContext.BaseDirectory` as well.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appcontext.basedirectory