# AlprNet hosted in Windows service failed to load

Tags: c#, windows-services, openalpr

When I run this code under my account in Visual Studio debugger

```
_alprNet = new AlprNet("eu", "openalpr.conf", "runtime_data");
if (!_alprNet.IsLoaded())
{
    Tools.LogError("!!! OpenALPR failed to load.");
```

It works OK and AlprNet loads.

But when I install the Windows service and start this service I get 
`"!!! OpenALPR failed to load."` 
with no additional information.

I have all the DLLs and the `runtime_data` in the folder where my windows service's exe file is installed, exactly the same way as it is in `bin\Debug` folder.

How to find the reason why AlprNet failed to load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it is useful for anyone:

This line in `OnStart` method before creating `new AlprNet`  fixed the problem:

```
System.IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10385563/2224701

Apparently the non .NET DLLs dependencies could not be solved without this.