# ASP.NET CORE : it is possible to query if running as a Windows service or as a console application?

Tags: asp.net-core

Using UseWindowsService to host asp.net core as a Windows service, is there a reliable way of understanding if the application is indeed running as a Windows service or as a console application? I'm asking because in one case (console) GetCurrentDirectory returns the correct current folder while in the other (Windows service) it always returns the "x:\WINDOWS\system32" folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer myself, `WindowsServiceHelpers.IsWindowsService()` returns exactly what I need, information as to if a windows service or a console application is running.

Answer (score 1):

See this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36631061/11244339)

Use **System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath)** for a more reliable way to get the current folder for Windows Services or Console apps.