# Windows service gives error System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException

Tags: c#

I get an error of

```
> Application: RfidService.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319
> Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
> Exception Info: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException    at
> System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32, System.String)    at
> System.IO.FileStream.Init(System.String, System.IO.FileMode,
> System.IO.FileAccess, Int32, Boolean, System.IO.FileShare, Int32,
> System.IO.FileOptions, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, System.String, Boolean,
> Boolean, Boolean)    at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(System.String,
> System.IO.FileMode, System.IO.FileAccess, System.IO.FileShare, Int32,
> System.IO.FileOptions, System.String, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean)
```

This is in the event viewer when I start my service application. It can be installed and it starts but in the event viewer it gives me the error mentioned above so it doesn't work. The only file that is needed is in the bin already and this is how I invoke it in the code.

```
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + $@"\JsonData\ApplicationSetting.json"))
{
    var jsonString = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    _applicationSetting = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApplicationSetting>(jsonString);

    if (_applicationSetting != null)
    {
        _pcsConnectionString =
            $@"Data Source={_applicationSetting.PcsSetting.DataSource};Initial Catalog={_applicationSetting.PcsSetting.InitialCatalog};user={_applicationSetting.PcsSetting.User};Password={_applicationSetting.PcsSetting.Password}";
        _lcsConnectionString =
            $@"Data Source={_applicationSetting.LaneSetting.DataSource};Initial Catalog={_applicationSetting.LaneSetting.InitialCatalog};user={_applicationSetting.LaneSetting.User};Password={_applicationSetting.LaneSetting.Password}";
        _serviceConnectionString =
            $@"Data Source={_applicationSetting.ServiceDatabase.DataSource};Initial Catalog={_applicationSetting.ServiceDatabase.InitialCatalog};user={_applicationSetting.ServiceDatabase.User};Password={_applicationSetting.ServiceDatabase.Password}";
        _sendingDelay = _applicationSetting.LcsSetting.SendingDelay;
        _activeQueueTimeInterval = _applicationSetting.LcsSetting.ActiveQueueTimeInterval;
        _messageLoggerEngine = new MessageLoggerEngine(_serviceConnectionString);
    }
}
```

What can I try to resolve this?

### Edit

The application exe and the folder where the json file resides in the same directory. See this image:

[image]

Comment: The exception is coming from this line: `var streamReader = new StreamReader(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + $@"\JsonData\ApplicationSetting.json")`, verify that this is a valid path.

Comment: `GetCurrentDirectory` is the current working directory of the app, which is *not* necessarily the same as the directory of your `.exe`.

Comment: @RyanWilson, when I run my console application, it runs fine. It can find the directory and the file. It's just when I run it as a service, it gives me that error.

Comment: @dxiv Please see my Edit. Thank you.

Comment: @Ibanez1408 log the path returned by `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory` when running it as a service and check to see if it's returning what you think it is

Comment: Try this `System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` instead of `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory`

Comment: @Ibanez1408 See [Windows service - get current directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376253/windows-service-get-current-directory).

Comment: @RyanWilson  I get this value "D:\RfidService\bin\Debug\JsonData\ApplicationSetting.json" which is actually correct.

Answer (score -1):

You can use

`using (var streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + $@"\JsonData\ApplicationSetting.json"))`

Comment: How does this fix the problem ?

Comment: How is this any different than what the OP is already doing?

Comment: You can use Relative path 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13342123/how-to-get-relative-path-of-a-file-in-visual-studio

Comment: That's what I did already. What's the difference?

Comment: @Asad The line you posted is copied straight from OP's code. This is not an answer, and should not be posted as an answer. You can post comments, instead, for other questions or clarifications.